# Программа для вывода на экран нажатой клавиши

Tags: c++

Нужно написать программу на С++ которая бы выводила на экран название клавиши которую я нажал. Например: я нажал пробел -> cout << "Vy najali SPACE".
Буду признателен как за готовый код, так и за всяческие подсказки(например что нужно гуглить). Есть огромное желание учиться, так что буду признателен любой полезной информации кроме ответа по топику!(Естественно более менее связанной с последним)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: в итоге написал сам.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    _getch();
    while (_getch() != 27)
    {
        if (_getch() == 13)
        {
            cout << "You've pressed ENTER. Key code is '13'" << endl;
        }
        else if (_getch() == 32)
        {
            cout << "You've pressed SPACE. Key code is '32'" << endl;
        }
        else if (_getch() == 9)
        {
            cout << "You've pressed TAB. Key code is '9'" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "You haven't pressed any of those: TAB, ENTER or SPACE."     << endl; 
            cout << "To exit the programm press ESC" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
enum class Keys
{
    NOSET,

    LEFT = 75,
    RIGHT = 77,
    TOP = 72,
    DOWN = 80,
    ESC = 27,
    SPACE = 32,
    ENTER = 13,

};
void main()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(_kbhit()) // слушатель нажатия на клаву
        {
            switch(static_cast<Keys>(_getch())) // ждёт нажатия на клаву без Enter после этого
            {
                case Keys::TOP: //вверх
                    cout << "Up" << endl;
                    break;
                case Keys::DOWN: //вниз
                    cout << "Down" << endl;
                    break;
                case Keys::LEFT: //влево 
                    cout << "left" << endl;
                    break;
                case Keys::RIGHT: //вправо
                    cout << "Right" << endl;
                    break;
                case Keys::ESC: //вправо
                    exit(0);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Не работает `/home/lol4t0/test/2.cpp:2:21: fatal error: windows.h: Нет такого файла или каталога`

Comment: Код платформозависимый так как идёт подключение файла по названию которого явно указана ОС, тут тяжело не заметить. Код рабочий и проверен перед отправкой. Возможно вам помогут ответы на данном сайте, а именно:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80788/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-windows-h-no-such-file-or-direc
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748896/cannot-open-windows-h

Comment: вот именно, что платформозависимый. А в вопросе ничто не сказано о платформе. И в ответе у вас, кстати, тоже не сказано (потому что у вас вообще ничего в ответе не сказано)